# how can i display elements content from getElementByTagName by using document.write() with index number?

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    <p>paragraph first</p>
    <p>paragraph second</p>
    
    <script>
        function f1()
        {
          
           var x =document.getElementsByTagName("p");
           
           
           document.write( x[0].innerHTML);
           document.write( x[1].innerHTML);//this is not working 
           
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` replaces all the `HTML` content of the screen with the new contect specified in the `document.write`. In your case you makes `document.write` twice. on the first execution , the content of the dom get replaced and makes the second selector `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].innerHTML` unavailabele, because there is no `p` tag existing in DOM now

If you want to display content of both `p` tag you have to collct the data from both tag and make a combination of both content and use `document.write` with the combiation of both. Aworking fiddle is attached below.

```js
function f1() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  const node1 = x[0].innerHTML;
  const node2 = x[1].innerHTML;
  document.write(`${node1} <br> ${node2}`)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens in the line `document.write( x[0].innerHTML);` is that everything in the document is overwritten by that line, so in the next line the original paragraph is gone.

`document.write()` is not that useful. Try something like this:

```html
<p>paragraph first</p>
<p>paragraph second</p>

<script>
  function f1() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

    output.innerHTML += x[0].outerHTML;
    output.innerHTML += x[1].outerHTML;
  }
</script>
<button onclick="f1()">Click</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: never use `+=` on `.innerHTML`.  It causes the current DOM to be converted into an HTML string, then _destroys_ the original DOM (removing any event handlers), appends the new string contents, and then creates a new DOM from that.

Comment: A "clean" solution would be `output.innerHTML = x[0].outerHTML + x[1].outerHTML;`

Comment: @Alnitak Point taken. I could rewrite the code, do clone, append etc. But we don't know what exactly OP would like to achieve, so better stick to the simple setup "in the same language" as the question.

Comment: The question doesn't use `+=` on DOM elements.